# How to set a cell value using the result of a parameterized SQL query using Power Query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, power-query

I have a worksheet with columns A, B and C. Then I need to run a query on my SQL Server using the values from columns A and B to find the value that should be placed on column C.

I've created the query like this:

SELECT * FROM Tablename

Then added the filtering steps considering two parameters I've created on Power Query Editor.

Now, how can I connect this existing worksheet to the query, passing the cells values as parameters to get the result (single row)?

### UPDATE

Adding more info...

My worksheet is like this:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
   1     |  223     |    ?
   2     |  545     |    ?
   8     |  542     |    ?
```

Then my database table has all of these 3 columns (along with several others that are not important), I need compare columns A and B from the worksheet with the equivalent columns A and B in the database table, to return column C value from the database (without importing the entire table into a new worksheet).

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I best understand your question, it appears that you have successfully created a Parameterrized Query and most likely you have put ? for the Field Value and you are able to retrieve the results by passing values to it.

Now you need to refer the Cell Value as Parameter values.

Try these steps.

1. Select the Table Go to Design Tab and go to Properties
2. Click the button next to Connection Name. 
   [image]
3. Go to Definition Tab. If you have correctly created a Parameterized Query, Parameter Button should be enabled for you.
4. For the specified parameters now select radio button 'Get the value from the following cell' and enable Refresh automatically when cell value changes.
   [image]
5. Click OK on all Dialog Boxes and exit.

Now ideally the query shall run everytime you update the values in your Excel sheet cells.

See the below example based on MS Access database. I hope the steps should be quite similar on SQL Server too. Do explore and experiment further. Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Almost there, @pat2015. The problem is that my worksheet has several rows for these columns A and B, so I can't use a fixed row in the parameter value.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira,, Pat suggested Access Query but you have written SQL Server,, !!

Comment: You're right @RajeshS. I didn't see that he was using Access.

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have not specified whether you have connected to MY SQL or not therefore, I would like to show you the easiest process to Export Excel File to MY Sql.*

**Follow these stepts to Export Excel worksheet data to a MySQL table.**

1. Select Data Tab, Click MySQL for Excel to open the MySQL for Excel task pane.
2. From the "Open a MySQL Connection", Double-click on existing Local or Remote connection to display the available Database Schemas.
3. Select Schema & Click Next to display all Database Objects.
4. Then Select the Cells in the Worksheet to Export, Click Export Excel Data to New Table.
5. Now, Specify whether the First Row should be used as the Column name.
6. Then type Unique Table name, and Select the collation to use for the New Table.
7. Choose the Primary key column.
8. Apply the appropriate options for the Columns.
9. Finally, Click Export Data to create the new table with data.

*Other Method is ODBC to create the DSN.*

**Note,,,** the **Select * from TableName**, pulls all records from the Table for all Columns.

*Since you are struggling with Parameter so, for the successful Query it needs to Declare the Parameter first.*

Here is one example.

```
DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(20)
SET @Parameter = 'Amit'

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Name = @Parameter
```

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: That's not what I need. I don't want to import the worksheet's data into the SQL Server database, I need to query a database table to add some data to my worksheet, but using the worksheet existing data as a parameter. Column A and B contains the parameter values, and the column C must be updated with the result from the SQL Server query.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira, actually I've  suggested 2 different methods. First is to Export Excel Sheet to SQL Server for further actions and Second one, how to create Parameter while Query. BUT your  problem is different. Actually you want to INSERT QUERIED data FROM SQL Server to EXCEL. And this is simply EXPORT to EXCEL.

Comment: Check my recent Answer, there I've suggesting 2 methods, one is to Export to Excel and Second how to Insert Queried data into Excel Sheet as the CSV file.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not getting it right, but I can't have a fixed value for the parameters, I need to query using each row of an existing worksheet and update the column C of the respective row.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira, did you try my RECENT SOLUTION,, I've posted on yesterday only,!

Comment: your solution will require the execution of this query using a tool like SSMS, it uses a fixed value as a criteria and won't return the data in the right position (column C of an existing worksheet, in the corresponding row of the filter values which area columns A and B) without additional steps. I know I can do this using VBA and using import/export features from the SSMS, but my question is related to the Excel and Power Query editor as the question tag points to.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira,, did u even write before that,,, you need Power Query to get involve ??

Comment: don't get me wrong, but it is in the question tags and I've mentioned the query editor. I really missed the "power" part in the question text, but I'll add. Thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

*Below is the best possible answer I can suggest you, after what I've realized by read the comment on my First Answer and the OP (Question posted by you), again.*

**Method 1: Export SQL Queried Data to Excel.**

While Query the Data, in the Results Window, just Click the Top Left Cell to Highlight Records, then Right Click Top Left Cell, and Click "Save Results As".

You may select the best File type to Export, is CSV File.

*In other words Export SQL Query data to Excel.*

**Method 2: Create Query statement to Export to Excel.**

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
   ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
   'Excel 9.0;Database=D:\Sales.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM Sales where Code = 1000')
```

*Other is below written Query directly places Data to Excel as CSV File.*

```
SELECT * FROM Sales where Code = 1000 INTO OUTFILE 'D:/Sales.CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
 ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**NB:** *Alter File, Field name and also the Criteria according to your Database Structure.*

*I do believe this will help you.*